# Affix Bootstrap falling onTop of Sub Navigation instead of above, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot share the link to the webpage at the moment for confidental reasons but I will describe my issue as much as possible with the required code.

I am running the affix javscript from Bootstrap 3.3.6 and have built the page on anchor points so that the the menu stays affix right above a sub navigation.

My **order of elements** are:

```
[MAIN]
[HEADER]
[CAROUSEL]
[NAV]
[ABOUTBOX]
  [CONTAINER/ROW]
   [SUBNAV]
[LIBRARYBOX]
  [CONTAINER/ROW2]
   [SUBNAV2]
[CONTACTBOX]
  [CONTAINER/ROW3]
   [SUBNAV3]
[FOOTER]
[/MAIN]
```

The **Affix JS** I am using

```
//AffixJS
var tfv=$('#carousel-nmhead').offset().top+$('#carousel-nmhead').height();
$('#navbar-main').affix({
  offset: {
    top: tfv,
    bottom: function () {
      return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true));
    }
   }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
 }
 .affix-top {
     position: static;
 }
 .affix-bottom {
     position: absolute;
 }
```

**The Issue**

Essentially the nav drops correctly right above my sub navigation as planned **once the "affix" class is set**

The moment it is still on "affix-top" then on the first click/interaction with the menu - the nav overlaps the sub navigation and it is only on the subsequent click that the nav will reposition itself anew

**Attempted solutions**

Add

- negative margins/paddings,
- create new anchor divs within the main 3 content divs
- tried debugging this different or fixed heights on the containers instead of min-height 0 !important;
- other minute misc. troubleshooting
- gone through  google dev tools to inspect and play around with the JS HTML and CSS but no luck

I am the only one working on CSS/JS at the firm and the only colleague with similar exp cannot comprehend why the Affix is not working on the first click/interaction with the nav but only on the subsequent ones

If you click on ABOUT (nav has About/Library/Contact as links) the page bounces down to About and if you click ABOUT a second time it scrolls up and since that is when the affix commences, the sub navigations suddenly pops out underneath.

Afterwards with the "affix" class set if you click on LIBRARY or CONTACT then you correctly bounce between them showing the sub navigation each time.

However if you click on ABOUT anew then the state goes back to the top of the page and you have click on the button twice again so that the sub navi pops out underneath

If this can't be trouble shooted without code I'll try to make a blank page so that we can clearly see the impact

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an affix not updating until I clicked somewhere in the body. I fixed it by adding `$(element).affix('checkPosition')`

Comment: Where did you add that precisely? A whole new line `$(element).affix({'checkPosition'});` ?

Comment: My particular scenario was happening when hiding/showing the element. So I added it immediately after re-showing it. Prior to that, it wouldn't update until I clicked on something.

Comment: I see but slightly confused, did you add it within the AffixJS script to call your affix or was a whole new JS function - bit confused - can you provide the full syntax or your Affix call ? :)

Comment: I did it as a whole new line: `$('#element').show().affix('checkPosition');`